# MySQL query from PHP script not inserting new records

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a PHP script which I built off of a MySQL query that reads from one database and inserts into another and should update on duplicate keys.

I completed this the other day, ran it in powershell throughout the day and it did the initial insert and updated appropriately throughout. I got back to work today, ran it in powershell and I got my successful connection message in powershell, no errors, but the database table did not Insert the new records for today.

For comparison, the query that I run in workbench on a test version of the table is inserting new records perfectly every day and updating throughout as well.

Without errors, I can't tell exactly why this script is not inserting new records today.

I'll post all the resources below, but for the details, the table structure is exactly the same (ID as AI primary key, Unique index on extension and Date_of_report)

Here is the script:

```
    $servername = "";
    $username   = "";
    $password   = "";

    $servername2 = "";
    $username2   = "";
    $password2   = "*";

    // Create connection
    $conn  = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
    $conn2 = new mysqli($servername2, $username2, $password2);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    echo "Connected successfully";

    // Check connection2
    if ($conn2->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn2->connect_error);
    }
    echo "Connected successfully";

    $data = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT c.extension ,
                                       RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID ,
                                       sum(Duration) AS Total_Talk_Time_seconds ,
                                       round(sum(Duration) / 60,2) AS Total_Talk_Time_minutes ,
                                       sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) AS Total_Outbound ,
                                       sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0)) AS Total_Inbound ,
                                       sum(if(Answered = 1,0,1)) AS Total_Missed ,
                                       sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) + sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0)) AS Total_Calls ,
                                       NOW() AS Time_of_report ,
                                       curdate() AS Date_of_report
                                FROM cdrdb.session a
                                INNER JOIN cdrdb.callsummary b ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
                                INNER JOIN cdrdb.mxuser c ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID
                                WHERE b.ts >= curdate()
                                  AND c.extension IN (7295,
                                                      7306,
                                                      7218,
                                                      7247,
                                                      7330,
                                                      7000,
                                                      7358)
                                GROUP BY c.extension");


    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn2, "INSERT INTO jfi.ambitionphone(Extension, ExtID, Total_Talk_Time_seconds, Total_Talk_Time_minutes,Total_Outbound, Total_Inbound, Missed_Calls, Total_Calls, Date_of_report,Time_of_report)
                                    VALUES (?,
                                            ?,
                                            ?,
                                            ?,
                                            ?,
                                            ?,
                                            ?,
                                            ?,
                                            ?,
                                            ?) ON duplicate KEY
                                    UPDATE Total_Talk_Time_seconds =
                                    VALUES(Total_Talk_Time_seconds), Total_Talk_Time_minutes =
                                    VALUES(Total_Talk_Time_minutes), Total_Inbound =
                                    VALUES(Total_Inbound), Total_Outbound =
                                    VALUES(Total_Outbound), Missed_Calls =
                                    VALUES(Missed_Calls), Total_Calls =
                                    VALUES(Total_Calls), Time_of_report = NOW()") or die(mysqli_error($conn2));



    // Create the main array
       $content = [];

    while ($d = mysqli_fetch_array($data, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "iiidiiiiss", $d['extension'], $d['RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID'], $d['Total_Talk_Time_seconds'], $d['Total_Talk_Time_minutes'], $d['Total_Outbound'], $d['Total_Inbound'], $d['Total_Missed'], $d['Total_Calls'], $d['Time_of_report'], $d['Date_of_report']) or die(mysqli_error($conn2));
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die(mysqli_error($conn2));

        // Store the current row
        $content[] = $d;

    }

// Store it all
file_put_contents('ambitionLog.json', json_encode($content, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
```

The original query that is inserting/updating perfectly in workbench:

```
INSERT INTO test.ambition_test (extension, extid, total_talk_time_seconds, total_talk_time_minutes, total_outbound, total_inbound, missed_calls, total_calls, time_of_report, date_of_report)
SELECT c.extension,
       responsibleuserextensionid,
       Sum(duration),
       Round(Sum(duration) / 60,2),
       Sum(IF(legtype1 = 1,1,0)),
       Sum(IF(legtype1 = 2,1,0)),
       Sum(IF(answered = 1,0,1)) -- , count(DISTINCT b.NOTABLECALLID) as Total_Calls
 ,
       Sum(IF(legtype1 = 1,1,0)) + Sum(IF(legtype1 = 2,1,0)) AS total_calls,
       Now(),
       Curdate()
FROM cdrdb.session a
LEFT JOIN cdrdb.callsummary b ON a.notablecallid = b.notablecallid
LEFT JOIN cdrdb.mxuser c ON a.responsibleuserextensionid = c.extensionid
WHERE b.ts >= Curdate()
  AND c.extension IN (7295,
                      7306,
                      7218,
                      7247,
                      7330,
                      7000,
                      7358)
GROUP BY c.extension ON duplicate KEY
UPDATE total_talk_time_seconds =
VALUES (total_talk_time_seconds) , total_talk_time_minutes =
VALUES (total_talk_time_minutes) , total_outbound =
VALUES (total_outbound) , total_inbound =
VALUES (total_inbound) , missed_calls =
VALUES (missed_calls) , total_calls =
VALUES (total_calls) , time_of_report = now();
```

Comment: I think this may be due to the fact that you're using `$conn` for the `$data` query, yet using `$conn2` as the argument for `mysqli_error()`. I could be wrong but it looks like it's playing a role here. It's probably also losing the connection; I don't know why you're using 2x different connections.

Comment: First of all...try an `echo "<pre>"; print_r($stmt); echo "</pre>"; `  and see if the values are correct/filled do the same with `$data` ...I believe there's something wrong within the select

Comment: Try writting the query in a separate variable and not inside the `my_sqli_query`, it's easier to spot errors this way...

Comment: @DiéfaniFavaretoPiovezan trying to echo errors now to see and I will update within a few minutes.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I added $conn to the error statements but still no errors printing. Also, I'm using 2 connections because I'm selecting data from a database server with read only access and inserting to a table on our production database with all privileges.

Comment: I also don't know why you're using `or die(mysqli_error($conn2))` for [`mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). That should be used on the query, not the binding itself. See if error reporting yields anything also http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Narrow the problem. Do a count of $d to see if the firts query is brining what you expect or if ti is the second query that is not inserting.

Comment: One other thing; if the column length(s) are too short for the data going in or the wrong type(s), your query may be failing silently. That's pretty much all I can come up with now.

Comment: @TomN. Ugghh.. it just dawned on me now; you never selected any databases. I guess I was looking at the rest of your code for too long *lol!*

Comment: Thanks everyone, I fixed my error statements and found that I had something out of order in my query.

Comment: @Fred-ii- if that were the issue it never would have worked the other day, right? I have my database appended to my table names in my queries

Comment: @TomN. that's a bit vague; can you add some details?

Comment: @TomN. that's what I find to be odd *lol!* oh well. My oversight.

Comment: so in my select statement, I have database cdrdb. 'tablename' and jfi.'ambitiontest'